# How to make double group by query with conditions with count function in linq?

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I am seeking for 2 days but I could not find any solution of my problem.First of all I want this output:

```
DeviceId -LogType   - EventCount

1   -  1  - 25

1-   2-   5
2-   1 -  10
```

I have lots of data in my database and I want to group them by 2 column. I am using MongoDb.

I have this class:

```
class EventReport
{
    public string DeviceId{ get; set; }
    public string LogType { get; set; }
    public string EventCount{get; set; }
}
```

I want to group data and create a EventReport list according to them.And here is my query:

```
var query = from x in ObjectMongoCollection.AsQueryable<DataLog>()
                    where (x.LogStatus == Enums.LogStatus.Alarm)
                          && (x.ReadingDateUTC >= startDateUTC &&x.ReadingDateUTC <= endDateUTC)
                          && (x.DeviceId == deviceId || deviceId == "")
                          && deviceIdList.Contains(x.DeviceId)
                          && x.LogType == LogType   
                    select x;
```

And I have this List:

List-EventReport- reports;

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: One step to solving your problem might be to give people some idea of your "input" data as opposed to just what you expect to get out of it.

Comment: And what actualy happends

Comment: If I understand what you mean by input data, my data named "DataLog" has lots of column including deviceID  and Logtype. There are lots of logs which come from the same device and whose Logtypes are the same .

Comment: The query does not group them, and when I tried to group them I can reach the count, but this time I lost the information that which device has this count.